# Automated testing for Air application (HTML/JS/CSS)

Tags: air, automated-tests

I have been developing a little Air application which is now starting to get quite cumbersome to test manually. I've searched through the internet for a testing framework, but it seems as if all existing solutions assume you're using Flex.

What I am looking for a free testing framework/toolset for creating automated functionality tests for Adobe Air "Ajax" applications. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same boat & would also like to find a solid way to test our (large) app properly (functional tests, we're already doing Unit Testing).

Okay, after some digging around (and haven't really tried it yet, so YMMV):
http://corlan.org/2008/08/15/functional-testing-framework-for-air-ajax-apps-based-on-selenium/

There isn't much in the way of a HowTo on the web page, but if you download the .zip there is a nice .pdf document there to help you on your way.

Curious to know how well this works for others...

Cheers,
-Chris